# Why does multi layer perceprons outperform RNN in CartPole?

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Recently, I compared two models for a DQN on CartPole-v0 environment. One of them is a multilayer perceptron with 3 layers and the other is an RNN built up from an LSTM and 1 fully connected layer. I have an experience replay buffer of size 200000 and the training doesn't start until it is filled up.
Although MLP has solved the problem under a reasonable amount of training steps  (this means to achieve a mean reward of 195 for the last 100 episodes), the RNN model could not converge as quickly and its maximum mean reward did not even reach 195 too!

I have already tried to increase batch size, add more neurons to the LSTM'S hidden state, increase the RNN'S sequence length and making the fully connected layer more complex - but every attempt failed as I saw enormous fluctuations in mean reward so the model hardly converged at all. May these are the sings of early overfitting?

```py
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_input, output_size, n_hidden, n_layers, dropout=0.3):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()

        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.n_hidden = n_hidden

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=n_input,
            hidden_size=n_hidden,
            num_layers=n_layers,
            dropout=dropout,
            batch_first=True)

        self.dropout= nn.Dropout(dropout)

        self.fully_connected = nn.Linear(n_hidden, output_size)

    def forward(self, x, hidden_parameters):
        batch_size = x.size(0)

        output, hidden_state = self.lstm(x.float(), hidden_parameters)

        seq_length = output.shape[1]

        output1 = output.contiguous().view(-1, self.n_hidden)
        output2 = self.dropout(output1)
        output3 = self.fully_connected(output2)

        new = output3.view(batch_size, seq_length, -1)
        new = new[:, -1]

        return new.float(), hidden_state

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size, device):
        weight = next(self.parameters()).data

        hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.n_hidden).zero_().to(device),
            weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.n_hidden).zero_().to(device))

        return hidden
```

Contrarily to what I expected, the simpler model gave a much better result than the other; even though RNN is supposed to be better in processing time series data.

Can anybody tell me what's the reason for this?

Also, I have to state that I applied no feature engineering and both DQN's worked with raw data. Could RNN outperform the MLP on using normalized features? (I mean feeding both models with normalized data)

Is there anything you can recommend me to improve training efficiency on RNN's to achieve the best results?

Answer (score 3):

> Contrary to what I expected the simpler model gave much better result that the other; even though RNN's supposed to be better in processing time series data.

There is no time series in the cart-pole, the state contains all the information needed for optimal decision. It would be different if, for instance, you would learn from images and you would need to estimate the pole velocity from a series of images.

Also, it is not true that the more complex model should perform better. On the contrary, it is more likely to overfit. For the cart-pole you don't even need a NN, a simple linear approximator with RBFs or random Fourier features would suffice. A RNN + LSTM is for sure an overkill for such a simple problem.

Comment: "There is no time series in the cart-pole" - that's right but I accumulated the observations to make things fit for LSTM. Probably wasn't the best idea.